# inequations - when is there no solution, or any x?

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve a few inequations and I got confused about something.

1) $x^2-3x+10<0$

$x^2-3x+10=0$

there is no solution for this, when I tried to solve the equation, I got a minus under the square root.
so the answer in the book is: no solution.

2) $-x^2+6x-10<0$

$x^2-6x+10>0$

$x^2-6x+10=0$

there is no solution for this equation, because there is a minus under the root.
and the book's answer is: any x

both cases are the same, but the answer is different and I don't understand why.

---

another case:

3) $x^2-12x+36 >= 0$ (equal and greater than..)

$x^2-12x+36=0 $

$x = 6$

the answer in the book: any x.

4) $-4x^2+12x-9>0$

$x=3/2$

book's answer: no solution.

both cases are the same, but the answer is different and I don't understand why.

Comment: A second-degree polynomial with a zero discriminant is always non-negative or always non-positive according to the sign of the leading coefficient.

Comment: Consider $x^2>-1$ and $x^2<-1$. The equality $x^2=-1$ has no real solution, but what do you think the solutions to the two different inequalities are? To generalize this, you must complete the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all of these you can complete the square.  For the first $x^2-3x+10=(x-\frac 32)^2+\frac{31}4$ and for the second $-x^2+6x-10=-(x-3)^2-1$  The first is positive for all $x$ because the square is positive and so is the other term.  The second is negative for all $x$.  When you turn the inequality into an equality you are looking for the boundary between parts of the real line that satisfy the inequality and those that do not.  When you get no solution you know that either the whole line satisfies the inequality or it does not.  You can try any point to check which is the case.  In your second case the quadratic is an exact square, so is tangent to the $x$ axis.  If 3 were $\gt$ instead of $\ge$, the result would be all $x$ except $x=6$.  You should make sure you understand why.